# Haskell - why does it has correct types?

Tags: haskell, monads

I was disappointed about fact that it correct typing:

```
renumberTree2' :: Tree a -> StateT Int Identity (Tree Int)
renumberTree2' t = get >>= (\v -> return (Empty))
```

After all, we have that:
`(>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`. Due to the fact that `StateT s m a` we can't give to bind `get :: StateT s m s`.  get is not of type `m a` as expected bind.
However, `get s` where `s :: s->(a, s')`  is correct type which should be given to bind.  Where am I wrong ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are mistaken in your reading of the types.  You can treat higher kinded types (those with type parameters) much like you would functions with precedence.  If you have a function

```
f :: a -> b -> c -> d -> e
f a b c d = undefined
```

Then calling it

```
let e = f a b c d
```

is equivalent to

```
let e = (((f a) b) c) d
```

Since `f a :: b -> c -> d -> e`, and so on for `(f a) b`, etc.

When you see the type `StateT s m a`, you can also read it as `((StateT s) m) a`, the types are equivalent and GHC will happily accept that syntax.  In this way it may be easier to see how `Monad m => StateT s m a` can be aligned with `Monad m' => m' a'`:

```
m' ~ StateT s m
a' ~ a
```

This implies that the `Monad m'` in question is `StateT s m`.  A simpler example that works in the exact same way is the `Functor` instance for `Either a`.  It isn't `Either` that has a `Functor` instance, but `Either a`, since a `Functor` is a type with kind `* -> *`, meaning a type that takes only one type parameter.

Comment: It seemed to me that monad always has type, it mean no `m`, always `m a`

Comment: @HaskellFun I think you're 80% of the way to understanding it fully. Here are a few points for you to research further. Only types with a kind of `*` can have values. Any type which you expect to have a value, such as one which appears to the right of `->`, must be of kind `*`. Monads have a kind of `* -> *`, which means you have to give them an argument of kind `*` to get a type of kind `*` out. However, you can still use your monad `m` on its own in other type expressions, such as `MonadTrans t => t m a`.

Answer (score 2):

> After all, we have that: `(>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`

```
> :type (>>=)
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

True.

> get is not of type `m a` as expected [by] bind.

```
> import Control.Monad.State
> :type get
get :: MonadState s m => m s
```

No, `get` is of type `m a` (though it does carry a constraint).

Answer (score 1):

`get` has type `m s` where `s` is the state type. The `MonadState` instance for `StateT` has context:

```
Monad m => MonadState s (StateT s m)
```

so the monad type `m` is `StateT s m`. Therefore the type of `get` for `StateT` is:

```
(StateT s m) s
```

The function given to `(>>=)` must have type `s -> StateT s m b` for some result type `b`.

```
return (Empty)
```

has type `StateT s m (Tree Int)` as required since `StateT s m` is a monad .